# sqlite with pandas, adding new column using pandas and try to change existing table with same table having new column

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
db=sqlite3.connect('School.sqlite')  //School.sqlite is a files name

data=pd.read_sql_query("select * from student",db) 
data["Address"]="TEST"  // adding new column in data dataframe 

//Student table is already exists
data.to_sql('Student',db,if_exists='replace')  // this line show error

//error show:  OperationalError: table "Student" already exists
```

as per as my understandning i write the correct code but it still showing error ,

Answer (score 0):

The table name argument is [case *sensitive*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22821) in the `to_sql` method for sqlite database.